# Finding primes using the Fibonacci sequence in modular form

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was wondering if the following is already a known result in mathematics. I have tested it and it seems to work every single time.

If I write the Fibonacci sequence in $\bmod (a)$ form and it repeats after $b$ terms, I will call this the period, and one of the two conditions is true then $a$ is a prime.

If $$b = \frac{a - 1}{n}$$ such that $\frac{a - 1}{n}$ yields a natural number.

Or:

If $b = n(a + 1)$

Then $a$ must be a prime number.

However if $a$ is a prime will not necessarily exhibit these properties.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You may be interested in http://math.arizona.edu/~ura-reports/071/Campbell.Charles/Final.pdf. I've also verified your result for all integers $a \leq 500$.

Comment: Star from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period). Also see [this older thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1100957/11619) (the title is only about modulo 3, but the discussion is more general). Also observe that whether $a+1$ or $a-1$ appears (your 2nd or 1st cases) depends on whether the prime is a quadratic residue modulo 5 or not. This is a consequence of Binet's formula (and quadratic reciprocity). If five is a non-residue, we need to use the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ to find a counterpart to $\sqrt 5$.

Comment: See [this answer of yours truly](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/150062/11619) for an example, where there is no $\sqrt 5$ modulo $p$ (there $p=503$). Not exactly your question but related. Here's why. By Binet's formula you are interested in the period of powers of the golden ratio modulo $a$. If $a\neq5$ is a prime that period is a factor of $a-1$ when $a$ is a prime such that $5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $a$, and a multiple of $a+1$ otherwise. If $a$ is a non-prime, then it's more complicated. In the former case it will be a factor of $\phi(a)$ instead of $a-1$. But that's not all.

Comment: The Fibonacci numbers have been studied extensively, and anything you can discover about them is probably already in the book *Fibonacci and Lucas Numbers with Applications* by Thomas Koshy. However, Koshy might approach your result from a slightly different angle, or it might not even be obvious.