# Which of the following numbers is a Fibonacci number; $(A) 75023$ $(B) 75024$ $(C) 75025$ $(D) 75026$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, square-numbers, golden-ratio

This question appeared in one of the mathematical societies exams in Saudi Arabia.

- No calculator is allowed.
- The required time to solve one question is $4$ minutes (on average).
- There is only one correct choice to each question.

> Which of the following is a Fibonacci number?
>
> $(A) 75023$ $(B) 75024$ $(C) 75025$ $(D) 75026$

**I thought about:**

Any number $n$ can be a Fibonacci number if and only if at least one of $5n^2+4$ or $5n^2-4$ is a perfect square.

**But** without using a calculator, how can I proceed? Is there this statement useful to solve this problem? Can we solve it using another useful statement?

**The Correct Option:**

$(C) 75025$ which is the $25^\text{th}$ Fibonacci number, I used WA to check.

---

Any help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Not a very satisfying or enlightening answer, but it seems perfectly feasible to calculate the 25th Fibonacci number in 4 minutes. Anyway, it seems at least as feasible as applying the perfect square test.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins that is a way of simple addition. However, it involves many steps, so, any small mistake will lead to a wrong answer (since the options are consecutive integers). If they were not consecutive, even with a mistake it may be ok.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432669/test-if-a-number-is-fibonacci) is a related question.  As you'll see, there aren't quick pencil and paper tests.  (at least, none I've ever heard of). Squaring a Fibonacci number (or candidate) isn't a great idea, since the $F_n$ grow so quickly.   And if you had a calculator to handle the squaring and factoring, well then the brute force method is a lot faster. I'd do it by hand.  You can simultaneously do it $\pmod {10}$ or something to avoid small careless errors.

Comment: To add onto Charles' comment, because every 2 steps in the fibonacci seequence multiplies your number between 2 and 3, and since $2^{10}\approx 1000$, we have that $75000$ is less than to $128*2^{10}=2^{17}$, so whichever number is the answer would be less then the 34th number in the sequence, and since $3^2$ is just shy of 10, $(3^2)^5$ is a bit shy of $100000$, so you're going to be at least the 20th number in the sequence.  This tells you approximately how far you need to go (splitting the difference between 20 and 34 gives 27), and so tells you that just computing is actually feasible.

Comment: The idea about carrying out a simultaneous mod 10 calculation is very good and should mitigate arithmetic errors. Perhaps there is some kind of modular trick that can be used to simplify the perfect square test. There is a standard result that  perfect squares are equal to 0 or 1 mod 4. If there is a way to solve this problem without direct calculation, I think it will lean heavily on eliminating wrong answers rather than proving that any of the answers is fibonacci.

Comment: One more comment on top of the suggestions already provided: if one knows the recurrence relations for $\langle F_{2n}, F_{2n+1}\rangle$ in terms of $\langle F_{n}, F_{n+1}\rangle$ (and more generally the matrix representations for $F_{a+b}$ in terms of $F_a$, $F_b$ and nearby numbers), then a sort of binary search can be done: start with, say, $\langle F_4, F_5\rangle$ and compute $\langle F_8, F_9\rangle, \langle F_{16}, F_{17}\rangle, \ldots$ until the numbers will clearly become too big; this should be just a few small multiplications. Then just 'walk' forwards the last few steps.

Comment: Modulo $11$, $F_n\not\equiv4$ and $F_n\not\equiv6$.  Since it is easily seen that $11$ divides $75020$ ($7-5-2=0$), only two of the four choices could be acceptable

Answer (score 3):

From the last part of the section [WICK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form)

If you know two F numbers in a row, you can double the index
$$ F_{2n-1} = F_{n-1}^2 + F_n^2 $$
$$  F_{2n} = 2F_{n-1} F_n + F_n^2        $$
$$ $$
$$ $$
$$   F_4 = 3, F_5 = 5 $$ so
$$ F_6 = 8, F_7 = 13 $$

doubling
$$  F_{13}  = 8^2 + 13^2 = 233   $$
$$ F_{14} = 2\cdot 8 \cdot 13 + 169 = 208 + 169 = 377 $$

back up one,
$$ F_{12} = 377-233 = 144  $$

$$ F_{25} = 144^2 + 233^2 =20736+54289 = 75025   $$

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to compute by hand $F_n \bmod 25$. As explained in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1100990), this sequence is periodic, but the first values, given in the table below, will suffice. Now, the given numbers (A)-(D) are respectively equal to $-2$, $-1$, $0$, $1$ modulo $25$. For $3\leqslant n \leqslant 44$, only one of these four values occurs in the table: $F_{25} \equiv 0 \bmod 25$. Thus the solution is (C).
\begin{array}{c}
\hline
0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14\\
\hline
0&1&1&2&3&5&8&-12&-4&9&5&-11&-6&8&2\\
\hline
\\
\hline
15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&\color{red}{25}&26&27&28&29\\
\hline
10&12&-3&9&6&-10&-4&11&7&-7&\color{red}0&-7&-7&11&4 \\
\hline
\\
\hline
30&31&32&33&34&35&35&37&38&39&40&41&42&43&44\\
\hline
-10&-6&9&3&12&-10&2&-8&-6&11&5&-9&-4&12&8\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Is $25$ the smallest modulus that works?

Comment: How did you figure out that you need to use mod 25